# LiveData does not observe changes when updated with SyncAdapter / different Thread

Tags: android, android-room, viewmodel, android-architecture-components, background-service

I have a SyncAdapter which inserts messages:

```
public class SyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {
       messageDAO.insert(..);
    }
}
```

And I have an Activity which displays a **filtered** part of these messages:

```
    protected Observer<List<MessageEntity>> messageOberserver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.messageOberserver = new Observer<List<MessageEntity>>() {
          @Override
          public void onChanged(List<MessageEntity> messages) {
            Log.v("tmp", "messages have changed");
            messageAdapter.setData(messages);
        }
      }

        MessageViewModel messageViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MessageViewModel.class);
        messageDAO.findMessagesForTopic(this.topicId).observe(this, this.messageOberserver);
  }
```

```
DAO:
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Message WHERE messageTopicId = :topicId")
    LiveData<List<MessageEntity>> messageDAO.findMessagesForTopic(String topicId);
```

Now the problem is that the observer does not recognize changes to the message table. Changes are displayed if I re-open the activity. What is a proper way for the SyncAdapter to tell the Activity that it should check for changes? I read about postValue(), but I don't know how to use it. The SyncAdapter does not know the partial Message data which is displayed by the Activity.

--

Btw. the code works if I update from other places (not SyncAdapter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a result of running your sync adapter in another process, which the sync adapter service documentation directs by default. Try removing the `android:process=":sync` or similar line from the service in AndroidManifest.xml. This will run the sync adapter in the same process as your application activity.

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing `messageOberserver` [sic] (`messageObserver`)

```
this.messageOberserver = ...
```

*after* passing it into the `observe` function.

```
observe(this, this.messageOberserver)
```

Your observer is null at this point. So the constructed observer is never registered and will never be called.

Comment: This was just a copy&paste error. It is not null. However it works when I do not use SyncAdapter. But I need to fix it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Room and multiple processes, make sure to enable enableMultiInstanceInvalidation to support update notification between processes.

```
        fun getDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            return synchronized(this) {
                if (!Companion::INSTANCE.isInitialized) {
                    val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context,
                        AppDatabase::class.java,
                        "media"
                    )
                        // TODO support migrations
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .enableMultiInstanceInvalidation()
                        .build()
                    INSTANCE = instance
                }

                INSTANCE
            }
        }
```